# Cancelar el evento FormClose y/o FormClosing

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, eventos

Quiero poder cancelar el evento FormClose y/o FormClosing.
Según he estado leyendo debo usar la propiedad **Cancel** de **FormClosingEventArgs.**
Sin embargo el evento **FormClosing no se ejecuta** cuando hago click en la X de la ventana para cerrarla.

```
       using System.Windows.Forms;    
       private void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result;
                result = MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el programa?",
                      "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);                

            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true
                return;
            }
        }
```

Por otro lado he intendado hacer exactamente lo mismo con el evento **FormClose**, en este caso **si se ejecuta** el evento al hacer click en la X, pero la propiedad **Cancel** no está definida en **FormClosedEventArgs**  y obtengo el siguiente error --> [Compiler Error CS1061](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061))

```
       using System.Windows.Forms;    
       private void FormClose(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result;
                result = MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el programa?",
                      "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);                

            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;//--> Error CS1061
                return;
            }
        }
```

He estado viendo la ducumentación de [FormClosedEventArgs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) y de [FormClosedEventArgs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formclosedeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) y no veo la forma para solucionar este problema.

Alguien sabe como hacer esto correctamente?
Muchas gracias!!

NOTA: El proyecto está hecho con .NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **evento** **FormClosed** ocurre después de que el formulario ya ha sido cerrado, en cambio el **evento FormClosing** ocurre en el momento justo en que se mandó a cerrar el formulario, es decir primero se ejecuta el **evento FormClosing** y después el **evento FormClosed**. Para preguntar al usuario si desea salir de la aplicación debes usar el **evento FormClosing**.

Prueba este código:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el programa?", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

O para hacerlo más corto:

```
e.Cancel = (MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el programa?", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No);
```

El **evento FormClosed** se usa más bien para saber la razones por las que se cerró el formulario y guardar dicha información si es de interés en un fichero externo accediendo para a ello a la **enumeración CloseReason**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación me ha aclarado mucho las cosas...y de repente el evento FormClosing ha empezado a funcionar asi que todo genial!! Saludos!!